# UI font underline

Tags: fonts, gui

[Image see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeulr.png)
Why this fonts are underline ? How can I disable this ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the underlined letters on the Menu items? That is simply the keyboard shortcut. So, for example, `Alt+F` will bring up the File menu.